# Autoencoder ambivalent about order of input data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, clustering, autoencoder

The problem I'm working to solve is this:

Given a musician's prerecorded free-form playing. I want to analyze each of the individual notes to determine how "in-rhythm" it is. See the graph in the screenshot.

[image]

The dark shading represents the beat intervals between *every* note in the vicinity of the one in question (plus or minus say, 10,000 ms) and every other in that vicinity. From this you are able to see peaks where common beat intervals lie and you can begin to deduce the length of a standard quarter note beat, etc.

The light thin lines represent the intervals between the *note in question* and those in the local vicinity. When I say I want to know how "in-rhythm" this note is, what I mean is, "how close are these lines to their nearest peak?"

It's basically a problem of cluster analysis. So, given a set of numbers (represented by the thin lines in the graph) how close are they as a set to the center of their respective clusters? It strikes me that this could be a good machine learning problem, so I've been attempting to approach it from that direction.

I was thinking a simple autoencoder would be suitable for the task. The input would be lists of numbers representing these beat intervals, but one thing I'm not sure about is this:

There's no telling how many of which peak/cluster any given note's beat intervals might belong to, so **is there a way to keep the neural net ambivalent about the order in the list it finds these numbers?** I don't want it determining that a certain note was more out of rhythm simply because it was missing an interval from a large cluster, etc.

It seems to me that order would probably always matter, so I'm at a bit of an impasse with my understanding. Am I right about this? Do you see some other solution?

Comment: >given a set of numbers (represented by the thin lines in the graph) how close are they as a set to the center of their respective clusters -- This is too vague. Can you formalize this, please? Do you want the average distance from each thin line to the nearest peak? If so that is just a simple calculation if you have the peak locations. Are you trying to compute the locations of the peaks automatically?

Comment: @Imran Yes and yes. For a given list of numbers, the average distance of each of those numbers from their nearest peaks would do just fine, but the main task is determining the location of the peaks themselves. And yes, really they should be referred to as clusters, because there will be tiny peaks as well as local peaks within the main spikes and these should be ignored.

Comment: The plan was to calculate everything in one fell swoop with the right neural net. I was figuring I could train on every list of intervals and then for any list of intervals in particular, I'd send it through the net and use the calculated cost as my measure of similarity.